# Azure Website each page loading slow

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've hosted a website on azure and right now I am deploying on a test slot and I have a problem after each deployment and if I haven't accessed the pages in a long time. Each page loads like 15 seconds and if accessed again loads in normal time. I changed the settings in the portal to keep the site always alive, but that doesn't work as expected. Tried with ping to the website every few minutes, but did not work again.

I thought the build is only once for the whole application, but it looks like that every file is built on-the-go. I am not sure how to fix that, or if it's even what I think it is.

Comment: What is the mode of your webapp?  Free, shared or basic/standard/premium?

Comment: Have you activated the "Always On" also for the test slot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pages will build and cache the first time you access any given page (not once for the whole site) right after deployment.  If you have public pages, you can also look at Application Initialization options in the web.config to do the "warm up" for you.

Comment: So there is no way to initialize them unless they are public pages?

Comment: I have this same issue with password protected pages (forms auth).  As far as I can find, the app initialization function will not work on any protected page -- so every time I republish my azure web app, I have to go in and manually hit every page to warm it up.  You can do this in a deployment slot and then swap too.