# Azure AppService repsonse slow after restart

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an AppService with a WebAPI project on it. After I restart this service or upload new version, each of endpoints I first call are responding very slowly (>15sec). If I click through all the endpoints once, the application works fine.

My Azure has a PayAsYouGo Subscription and I have `AlwaysOn` feature of `AppSercice` set to `true`. In the trace logs I also saw multiple entries with:

> SnapshotHelper::RestoreSnapshot - optout environment variable aspnet:PortableCompilationOutput=true

During compilation I'm using following parameters:

```
/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true 
/p:UseMerge=true 
/p:SingleAssemblyName=AppCode
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your Azure instance has not been called for the first time.  You need to use an application warm up process to get it going first.  One way to handle this is by using [application initialization module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization) configured via your [web.config during swaps and deployments](http://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/).

This allows you to call a page in your site as part of the startup process after you do your deployments.

```
<system.webServer>  
  <applicationInitialization>  
    <add initializationPage="/warmup-cache.php" hostName="appinitwarmup.azurewebsites.net"/>  
  </applicationInitialization>  
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have two additional questions. 1. What if each of my endpoints requires authentication, how does above solution will work in that case? 2. Do I need to put <add initializationPage ... record for each of my endpoints in WebAPI (there will be dozens of them)

Comment: You will only have to warm up each individual site.  If the endpoints are just two sections of the same API on the same website instance you will only have to call one since both would have their code loaded at that point.  The authentication doesn't matter as much since you just want the code 'hot' in memory and any application startup code ran before the first real call comes in.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but it looks that it not wokred for me. The site behaves like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333016/azure-website-each-page-loading-slow , but the strangest thing is that it only works this way on my pay as you go Azure subscription. On bizspark subscription the same site behaves differently - here I need to wait only once - when the site is loading the first time - then all other pages of this site loads quickly. On pay as you go I need to click on each individual page to and only then they works fast. Any idea why this differs based on 2 Azures?

Comment: They shouldn't behave differently. Can you check in the settings for the site if you have "always on" checked on one but not the other?